# Getting push notification details on app launch using swiftUI language

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm using SwiftUI language

I click on a notification and redirect to the home screen, but I need a detailed screen in a redirection.

This is my set root code.. how to set here detail screen using SwiftUI language

```
if(application.applicationState == .inactive)
    {
        // let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let contentView = ContentView1()

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            self.window = window

        }

        self.window?.rootViewController =  UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `NavigationView` and in it put `NavigationLink(_,destination:,tag:,selection:)` where `selection` is bound to a value that will match the notification received.

For a detailed explanation and example code, see https://nalexn.github.io/swiftui-deep-linking/ .